# String is interpreted as wildcard expression

Tags: regex, powershell, hyper-v

I am using PowerShell to manage Hyper-V remote server.
It has the VM machine named "Machine[text(ip)" and a'm trying to get virtual machine instance via `Get-VM` like so:

```
Invoke-Command  -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $machine = "Machine[text(ip)"
    $vm = Get-VM -Name $machine             
}
```

But all I get is an error:

> The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid.

It seems that powershell is considering `[` char to be metacharacter, so I tried all the following cases:

```
$machine = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($machine)
$machine = "Machine`[text(ip)"
$machine = "Machine``[text(ip)"
$machine = "Machine\[text(ip)"
$machine = 'Machine[text(ip)'
$machine = @'
Machine[text(ip)
'@
```

But nothing of that worked for me.

When I close the brackets `Get-VM` just returns `$null` (like "Machine[text]ip)").
When I run just `Get-VM` I have a list with the VM "Machine[text(ip)" in it (and "Machinetext" also).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special characters in the string are interpreted as [wildcards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088.aspx), not as a regular expression. The best way to avoid problems like this is to avoid using special characters in VM names.

With that said, I would expect `` "Machine`[text(ip)" `` to work (or ```` "Machine```[text(ip)" ```` should the string be interpreted twice). Can't test, though, because I don't have a Hyper-V installation at hand.

If escaping doesn't work at all use a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-Vm * | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Machine[text(ip)" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this as a workaround for getting a wildcard match:

```
$Wildcard = "Machine[[]text(ip)"
$Machine = 'Machine[text(ip)' 

$Machine -like $Wildcard
```

And it appears to work. You'll need to test it on your system.